# What to pass to ember-data if no records are found on server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The question is simple.

I've to retrieve a list of messages from the backend with ember, but there's the possibility that a specific user has none.

What response expects ember-data in theese situations? And what's the best way to handle them?

Thanke you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have a user with id `1234`, we might do a HTTP GET on `/api/users/1234/messages`.
If there were no messages for this user, ember-data would expect a payload like so:

```
{ "messages": [] }
```

Note that the top level (root) key of the payload is the plural of the Model's *typeKey* according to Ember Data. It is expecting a plural because we are asking for an Array of messages.

The *typeKey* is essentially a camelCase of the model's class name. If the model is `App.SuperVillain`, the *typeKey* will be `superVillain`. If you were asking the back end for a collection of SuperVillains, the root key would be `superVillains`.

```
{ "superVillains": [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return an empty object `{}`. Ember data should be fine with this.